# How to simplify groovy loop code

Tags: java, groovy, java-8

I have an groove code (with some java style elements)

```
dates.forEach new Consumer<Period>() {
    @Override
    void accept(Period period) {
        println period
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do it simpler?

I would like to have something like

```
dates.forEach println
```

or

```
dates.forEach println date
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use

```
dates.each { println it }
```

Comment: An alternate would be: `dates.each System.out.&println` - method references are closures.

Answer (score 2):

Groovy closures can fill any spot, where a single method interface is requested (same as Java lambdas behave).  So the code, you wished for, is already very close to what actually works:

```
groovy:000> [1,2,3].forEach{ println it }
1
2
3
===> null
```